# support a specific tls version for nginx server block

Tags: server, nginx

Our nginx server hosts multiple server blocks(hosts), which share the same ssl_protocols (TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2).

```
    http{
      ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2
    }
```

Recently, TLS for one host needs to be upgraded to TLSV1.3 and should not support any version under 1.3 for compliance, while other hosts should keep the same (some of their clients still use 1.2 and 1.1) for compatible purpose.

I tried add

```
   server {
      ssl_protocols TLSv1.3
   }
```

in the corresponding server block with the expection that instruction ssl_protocols can inside of server can overwrite the outside one. But the scan test shows that it is combination of all ssl_protocols instead of overwriting.

Is there any other solution for this issue: support a specific TLS version for a server without supporting other lower version.

Comment: `ssl_protocols` is used for enabling, so you should remove the global `http` block `ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2` and add that to the `server` blocks that require those to be enabled